# ColorPicker in android NullPointerException

Tags: android, color-picker

I am using this [file](http://www.yougli.net/wp-content/uploads/ColorPickerDialog.java), to choose color, its a nice dialog, I am using the following code

```
public class Main extends Activity implements
        ColorPickerDialog.OnColorChangedListener {

    Button b;
    Context c = this;
    ColorPickerDialog.OnColorChangedListener cc;

    /** Called when the activity is first created. */
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);
        b = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);
        b.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            
            @Override
            public void onClick(View arg0) {
                new ColorPickerDialog(c, cc, "tag", 16777215, 0).show();

            }
        });
    }

    @Override
    public void colorChanged(String key, int color) {
        Log.d("debug", "key is " + key + " color is " + color);

    }
}
```

in my `main.xml` there is just one button.
this code is working fine when I click on a button and dialog box appear, but when I select a color a `NullPointerException` is coming, I dont know why, any help will be thankful. Regards

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I changed my code to this that worked, I need to make onColorChangedListener inside the `onCreate` like this

```
public class Main extends Activity  {
Button b;
OnColorChangedListener cc;

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);
    cc=new OnColorChangedListener() {

        @Override
        public void colorChanged(String key, int color) {
            Log.d("tag", "key is " + key + " color is " + color);

        }
    };
    b = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);
    b.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View arg0) {
            new ColorPickerDialog(Main.this, cc, "tag", 16777215, 0).show();

        }
    });
}
}
```

[reference](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9916404/how-can-i-use-another-color-picker-without-preferenceactivity#comment12703042_9917392)

Answer (score 1):

In your case,

```
Context c = this;
ColorPickerDialog.OnColorChangedListener cc;
```

both are **null**,

```
new ColorPickerDialog(c, cc, "tag", 16777215, 0).show();
```

so, this line cause **NPE**..

Comment: Oh ! but what would I initialize `cc` :S

Comment: I think `c` is not null, cc is null but what i need to initialize it with ?

Comment: Post your complete code. Also instead of c use Main.this and debuge your code.

Comment: I gave the link of java file in first line of my question. ok i use Main.this thanks for comment.